# JavaScript/HTML Page Refresh Alert

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

I'm trying to make an alert in JavaScript which warns the user that they probably shouldn't reload the page. But I want them to be able to navigate to other pages without an alert, just not refresh the current page. I have found some alerts but they either provide alerts in both cases, or provide an alert and refresh the page anyway. I want the user to be warned and then be able to stop the page from refreshing. I guess it means that they also shouldn't be able to go back to the page once they have left it?

Comment: I've searched around a bit and I've been unable to find any reliable or definitive event which detects a page refresh. You might consider avoiding the situation where a page refresh is a problem. I can think of a couple of ways:
* on POST, show 'thanks for posting' or something like that, then redirect user via header or javascript to another page which shows what you want to show
* use AJAX to perform the post operation. If you do that, then the browser refresh button and/or F5 will not re-perform the AJAX but will refresh the current page.

Comment: The page is going to provide the user with a random number, and I just don't want them to be able to keep getting a new random number is all.

Comment: Consider storing it in a cookie. Something like 'if user does not have a cookie, assign them a new random number, otherwise take the random number from the cookie'.

Comment: Ahhh that sounds like an even better idea! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad to help. BTW, this is how sessions work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onunload="window.alert('Hello!');">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onbeforeunload` and set a variable as follows:

```js
var l=false;
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if (!l) {
    return "you shouldn't leave";
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="//google.com" onclick="l=true">Leave</a>
```

(This doesn't work on Run Snippet because it's in an iframe)

Comment: This is what I tried using, and it is good, but I want the user to be able to go on a different page.

Answer (score 0):

This you may find useful. In conjunction With above code;;;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
    #dialogoverlay{
    display: none;
    opacity: .8;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    border-radius:7px; 
    width:550px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox > div{ background:#FFF; margin:8px; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxhead{ background: #666; font-size:19px; padding:10px; color:#CCC; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxbody{ background: #333; padding:20px; color:#FFF; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxfoot{ background: #666; padding:10px; text-align:right; }
</style>
<script>
    function CustomAlert(){
    this.render = function(dialog){
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;
        var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
        var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
        dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
        dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
        dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
        dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
        dialogbox.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Acknowledge This Message";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
        document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Alert.ok()">OK</button>';
    }
    this.ok = function(){
        document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
function deletePost(id){
    var db_id = id.replace("post_", "");
    // Run Ajax request here to delete post from database
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById(id));
}
function CustomConfirm(){
    this.render = function(dialog,op,id){
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;
        var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
        var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
        dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
        dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
        dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
        dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
        dialogbox.style.display = "block";

        document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Confirm that action";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
        document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Confirm.yes(\''+op+'\',\''+id+'\')">Yes</button> <button onclick="Confirm.no()">No</button>';
    }
    this.no = function(){
        document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }
    this.yes = function(op,id){
        if(op == "delete_post"){
            deletePost(id);
        }
        document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }
}
var Confirm = new CustomConfirm();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox">
  <div>
    <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<p id="post_1">
  Today is a lovely day ...
  <button onclick="Confirm.render('Delete Post?','delete_post','post_1')">Delete</button>
</p>
<p id="post_2">
  I like pickles ... 
  <button onclick="Confirm.render('Delete Post?','delete_post','post_2')">Delete</button>
</p>
<button onclick="Alert.render('Hello World')">Custom Alert</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This allows you to give Custom alerts.
Explination of the code here: [Alert Box](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCL90kPID0A)